# Pandas and checking float values

Tags: python, pandas

Having real trouble finding answers to I hope simple question. I have two columns which a temperatures with decimal places `34.67777` and `56.53637` for example.

I just want to extract the rows where rowA value is higher than 35 and where row b value is lower than 50, for example.

I've tried formating my column data with `.istype(float)`

And then creating a `range()` where I can try to check the values using `isin`. But then the range won't deal with float values.

So pretty unsure what to do or how to go about checking

Comment: I'm not certain I understand.  does this help `df.query('A > 35 and B < 50')`

Comment: Do you think filtering like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas) ?

Comment: @jezrael not sure.  That's what it seems like.

Comment: @jezrael @piRSquared So as if the duplicate answer will:

`df.loc[(df[columnA'] > 50.123 ) & df['columA'] <90.456] & df.loc[(df[columnB'] > 20.765) & df['columB'] < 30.123]`

Return me rows where `df[columnA] ==67.898383 & df[columnB] == 25.123`. Do I need to account for float values at all?

Comment: hmmm, not sure if understand, do you think `df[(df['columnA'] > 50.123 ) & (df['columA'] <90.456) & (df['columnB'] > 20.765) & (df['columB'] < 30.123)]` ? What do you think `Do I need to account for float values` ?